# trouble printing line numbers and `alert`ing long string vars to debug JS script block

Tags: javascript

I need to incorporate some JS in my php.html page, and I am having a difficult time trying to debug. I have been googling but can't seem to find how to print line numbers, like `__LINE__` in php. Is there a way to achieve this seemingly useful feat easily enough?

Another problem I have is, I am trying to debug a `script` block that is not quite behaving, and I need to `echo`, er make that `alert` a var that is a very long string. The alert box unfortunately cuts itself off, presumably because of how long the var string is. There doesn't seem to be anyway to define parameters, such as height, width, etc. for the `alert` box, so I have tried using this hack:

```
function alertDebug(linesToDisable)
      {
        var newLinesToDisable = new String();
        for (var n = 0; n < linesToDisable.length; n++)
        {
          if (n % 100 == 0)
            newLinesToDisable += "\n";
          newLinesToDisable += aString[n];
        }
        alert( newLinesToDisable );
      }
      alertDebug( linesToDisable );
```

but the `alert` fails to fire altogether. Can anyone with L337 JS skills help with as well?

Comment: Use `console.log`, not `alert`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About debugging/long logs: the JavaScript `console` object has a lot of useful methods for debugging. You can find them all over at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console). The most common one being `console.log(newLinesToDisable)`.

About line numbers: usually browsers also expose the line number where the error was thrown (a stack trace), but if you want to specifically log a line number, you could try

```
var line = new Error().lineNumber
```

If that doesn't work in whatever environment you're using, you can try:

```
var stack = new Error().stack
```

But then you have to dig through the whole stack trace.